# Android Wifi connection exchange messages

Tags: android, android-wifi

Can two android devices share hello message just by enabling their wifi? They should not be connected to an internet network, but just should exchange messages when wifi turned on

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to send messages without being connected to an internet network.

For instance, [Jott](http://www.jott.com), an Android and iOS app, uses what's called a mesh network to allow users to send messages to each other when they are in close proximity. The mesh network operates on Bluetooth low energy or using a router that can reach within 100 feet of each user.

Not sure if this helps with your idea of enabling wifi, but it's something worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this myself but I read there is thing called Wi-Fi Direct that allows phones to connect each other without a Wi-Fi access point.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html